# MIPS: difference between &A[i-j] and A[i-j]

Tags: mips

I am learning MIPS assembly language in this [exercise website](http://egloos.zum.com/itfs/v/9714850)

in exercise 2.3, I wonder what the differences are for the following instructions

```
add $t1, $t1, $t0       # $t1 = &A[i-j]
lw  $t1, 0($t1)     # $t1 = A[i-j]
```

specifically, what are the differences between &A[i-j] and A[i-j]? I know that A is an array , but why is there a "&" sign, the other one is not? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

They're trying to explain the instructions in terms of C notation.

A[n] is the value in the n'th element of the array A

&A[n] is the address of the n'th element of the array A

The point of the quoted code is not to call out the 'difference' between two instructions; it is to show how to fetch the content of an array element.

The first instruction computes the address of the element by adding the content of $t0 to $t1 (and understanding how that produces &A[i-j] requires knowing what's in $t0 and $t1 beforehand).

The second instruction is what actually loads the word, using the address computed by the first instruction.